# Solving performance issue DrupalDatabaseCache::clear

Tags: performance

I am facing a performance issue when I open some of the pages.  It is taking too long time. After checking the queries and the time for each query I found that these two functions are taking a long time:

```
DrupalDatabaseCache::clear
DrupalDatabaseCache::set
```

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing performance problems using database as cache backend you should consider moving the caches to a better performing cache backend. Suitable backends for general caching are for example [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) and [Redis](http://redis.io/). For both of these you can find proper contrib modules ([Redis](https://drupal.org/project/redis) & [Memcache](https://drupal.org/project/memcache)) and a lot of help in using them. If you want to have high performance page cache you could use [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) for that. Also setting up [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) to improve general PHP performance is a wise thing to do. Some basic information on using APC can be found from [here](https://drupal.org/node/1777090).

Whatever caching methods you choose to use you should remember that form-cache must use non-volatile storage. This means that you should simply remember to keep form-cache in database. This can be achieved by inserting the following to your sites settings.php file.

```
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
```